# New version tensorflow installed (from 2.10.1 to 2.12.0) but in Jupyter Notebook import the old one

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

In Jupyter Notebook, using `import tensorflow as tf` , always the old version imported. How to import the new version?

Checked in IDLE Shell 3.11.3 2.12.0 is well installed.

```
Python 3.11.3 (tags/v3.11.3:f3909b8, Apr  4 2023, 23:49:59) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.__version__)

2.12.0
```

In Jupyter, when I run the same, I get 2.10.1

```
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.__version__)

2.10.1
```

Comment: Hi @YYY ZZZ, The python IDLE shell and conda environment are two different environments. So to have same tensorflow version in both the environment , you may need to install same tensorflow version in conda environment as python IDLE to let jupyter show the same Tensorflow version.